# Print prime numbers from a given number range. I cannot make the code work

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program in C++ to find prime number within a range. For example:

Input number for starting range: 1
Input number for ending range: 100
The prime numbers between 1 and 100 are:
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97

This is my actual code and I don't know why it doesn't work. Can you please edit the code without adding any new variables if possible?

```
int nr1;
int nr2;
bool check = true;
cin >> nr1;
cin >> nr2;
for (int x = nr1; x <= nr2; x++)
{
    for (int y = 2; y < x; y++)
    {
        if (x % y == 0)
        {
          check = false;
        }
    }
    if (check)
    {
        cout << x;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost fine, but after fixes it is not optimal for large number performance. This is a version with minimal updates and update comments:

```
int nr1;
int nr2;

bool check = true;
cin >> nr1;
cin >> nr2;

// must start from 2 if start is less than 2
if(nr1 < 2) {
    nr1 = 2;
}

for (int x = nr1; x <= nr2; x++) {
    // bring it inside loop
    check = true;

    // this is fine, but condition "y * y <= x" would be faster
    // also you repeat this check for all numbers
    // if you keep previous primary numbers in memory
    // you can loop only primary numbers
    for (int y = 2; y < x; y++) {
        if (x % y == 0) {
            check = false;
        }
    }

    // minor format fix
    if (check) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
}

// minor format fix
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anatoliy R! The code worked perfectly.